# Building mathematical graph of AC-DC voltage converter

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

I build the math function that describes the graphical operation of an electronic Wheatstone bridge (full-wave rectifier).
I arrived at the following solution I created a generative wave function (to match what we have from energy providers 60 Hz).

**<<Generative: $\ sin(T*\ 2pi*Hz) $**

[image: Generative]

where T is the time variable in the interval 0 .. N

2 represents a full wave neg. and pos. = hz

$\ pi$ is the constant used to aim wave phase shift by one Pi (calibration)

variable Hz is determined by the number of oscillations in time unit, in this case 60 Hz/sec..

Math absolute value function works exactly like diodes (eg. Wheatstone bridge), and applied to the generative function above, the graphic in this moment looks like.

**<<With full-wave rectifier: $\ abs(sin(T*\ 2pi*Hz)) $**

[image: With full-wave rectifier]

What I do not know, and i need some help there is how to represent graphical dischage of a capacitor applied to this graph, I do not understand how I could conceive a composed function so that when current sine value decrease below the max peak of it , to decress linear to the next wave at about 0.75 (sqrt (2) / 2) amplitude.

[image: Here look done]

I want to understand this, will help me a lot with how all electronic components works, next stage will be Fourier analysis.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes is exactly what I need but how I can apply this as a composed function to fit with graph,i mean at how loks the quadratic function applyed to my graph.

Comment: I am not able to solve this problem it is just too complicated for me.Thanks alot for your support.